# Why is there no Robin in the Nolan-directed Batman movies?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises, the-dark-knight, batman-begins, christopher-nolan

Although Robin seems to have an pivotal role in ruining earlier Batman movies, he's still an integral part of the Batman series. 
 
 Is there a reason why Robin does not appear in Batman Begins/The Dark Knight/Dark Knight Rises?

Comment: maybe he's just not that interesting to the writers

Comment: Or it could be that previous movies with Robin included were so dire that nobody wanted to do it again.

Comment: Killer Croc will NOT be making an appearance in any Nolan Batrman fils. He doesn't fit within a realistic universe. The black Mask, the Riddler and the Penguin would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's a matter of the director having a specific vision of how his Batman stories will become. In the first two films, Christopher Nolan wanted to bring Batman back to his roots, explore how Bruce Wayne became Batman, and how Batman became the legend he is (in the 1989 Batman film, when Vicki Vale asks Bruce why bats, he replies "They're great survivors"; in Batman Forever, we get a VERY brief glimpse of bats on Bruce's mind. That's all the motivation we get). Batman Begins was very much an origin story, showing also the training Bruce took to become Batman. The Dark Knight follows soon after that story, as the ending of Batman Begins sets up The Joker to enter the story.

The thing is, I tried looking up the reason, and I can't yet find any quotes online from Christopher Nolan (see [this article here](http://www.ropeofsilicon.com/did-christopher-nolan-ever-say-robin-wouldnt-be-in-the-bat-franchise-looks-like-no-he-didnt/) for an expanded story on this). The next film, The Dark Knight Rises, supposedly takes place 8 years after The Dark Knight. It also features Bane, a character who became notorious for eventually [breaking Batman's back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%3a_Knightfall). It's entirely conceivable that Nolan will include Robin in this film as his protege who can help him fight Bane. Nobody outside the film set really knows. Me, I'm looking forward to finding out in 2012.

Comment: Apparently, Nolan said this: `This is a young Batman, so Robin's a few films....not for a few pictures anyway. Dick Grayson's still in a crib somewhere. I seriously doubt I will even be involved when Robin's in the franchise" says Nolan.` in Lacenby News, and considering the secrecy of the entire franchise, I think this question should be **closed** as it has no definitive answer

Comment: @EknathIyer, the idea of Dick Grayson being 'in a crib somewhere' is commented on in the article I linked to. I don't know if this question necessarily should be closed or not - my vote would be to keep it open for now, as it is a legitimate question and someone else might yet come up with some information about if Robin will show up in the 3rd film or not.

Comment: Sounds fair to me.

Comment: There are plenty of rumors flying around, including this one as seen on Geek Tyrant - http://geektyrant.com/news/2011/9/2/rumor-will-joseph-gordon-levitt-play-robin-in-the-dark-knigh.html - I won't summarize it as it could be considered spoiler-ish, but I do take these rumors with a pinch of salt.

Comment: This should not be closed.  As of yet we still have one more Nolan Batman and the quote above I have seen before from Nolan, showing there is an answer and/or there could be a surprise in DKR that answers this question.

Comment: I don't agree about closing part..

Answer (score 34):

Robin is in the final Nolan directed Batman movie ("The Dark Knight Rises").  In the final few minutes of the movie, when Officer Blake (Joseph Gordon-Levitt) is collecting his property from the boys home, the woman behind the desk isn't able to find his name in their system.  He then gives her is 'real name,' after which she says "You should use your real name, I like it better (or something to that nature) . . . Robin."

The interesting part about the conclusion of the Dark Knight Rises is that it seems to be a set up for a "Robin" franchise in the next few years.  When Officer Blake discovers the batcave beneath Wayne Manor (Now the new home for Gotham's Orphans) it seems to be a 'passing of the torch' moment. Also when he is talking with Bruce Wayne about the similarities of their pasts, and at the end of the movie when he is talking with Gordon about why he is leaving the police force (i.e. the 'structure'). In fact, during the first thirty minutes of the movie, there even seems to be a set-up for who the villain will be for Robin . . . Killer-Croc.  When Commissioner Gordon is taken captive by Bane in the sewers, there is a brief mention by one of the officers of a "large crocodile" (or something using those terms) in the sewers.  I believe that Killer-Croc spent the majority of his time in the sewers in the comic series.  It seemed like an off the cuff kind of statement for a character, and pointless to have in the movie, since it's humor factor didn't really have too much of an impact.  I honestly believe it was a direct set up line for a Robin movie.

Comment: I think the croc reference was just that, a reference.  And considering this is the end of Batman as far as Nolan is concerned, I doubt there will be a Robin/Nightwing franchise coming.

Comment: @TylerShads Why should there be a Robin/Nightwing franchise? There are rumors about a forthcoming Batman reboot. I am not very familiar with the comics, but considering this answer http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/3467/418 I think it would be possible that Blake will be the next Batman(from what I know, it's the symbol that counts, just like it happens with The Green Lantern - also various articles read, no comics).

Comment: That's if Nolan is even doing this reboot.  Judging from the history of reboots, this reboot will wipe clean anything done with Nolan's Batman, starting anew.

Comment: A late comment, but since Batman has retired at the point where Blake discovers the Batcave, that would make him Nightwing rather than Robin -- even though Blake's given name is Robin.

Answer (score 15):

To keep it short:

The point of the Robin reference was to display that even though the audience did not know Blake was Robin, he still was. In some interview, someone close to the production of the movie mentioned how the purpose is that he was Robin the whole time, you only find out at the end. This represents perfectly what Batman says to Blake earlier in DKR, that his goal was only to inspire people. The purpose of Batman is not that only Batman can do it.

The message is that anyone has the ability to stand up for justice and protect his or her society. Some of the true heroes of the day are Gordon, Blake, and Selina (Selina actually SAVES Batman when Bane is about to kill him at the end of the movie). Making a Robin movie would veer away from the purpose and just present another hero of Gotham, while, conversely, the hero of Gotham is the soul of hope. And that belongs to anyone.

Answer (score 13):

Nolan has given an explanation for this. According to him the Batman portrayed in his movies is still young and according to comics Robin appears only when Batman grows old and hence needs a sidekick. Nolan has also said that in his trilogy Robin won't appear at all because these movies will present a young Batman.

Answer (score 11):

Christian Bale said that he wouldn't want to be Batman in this franchise if there was a Robin and Christopher Nolan obliged. Nolan said that he wouldn't fit the dark tone of the movies. Also Dick Grayson is very young when he becomes Robin, about 10 or 12. So that's another reason for not having him in the films.

Comment: references please

Comment: I do agree, please show some references.  I don't doubt this and think I have seen it before.  But , this doesn't mean we can't have Nightwing ;)

Answer (score 8):

He is in *The Dark Night Rises* with the cover name

> John Blake who is a rookie cop and a big fan of Wayne and "Batman". He also knew from when he was a kid that Wayne is The Batman.

In the final scene you hear a woman asking why he does not go by his real name, and then calls him "Robin".

Comment: he is never shown as Robin. He is shown as someone who inherits Batman's legacy taking ownership of the cave and Batman's ideal and will. Its implicit to understand that he might become the next Robin but still i wouldn't call that he was in the movie.

Answer (score 7):

Batman will be rebooted to fit in with the new DC Universe leading up to an eventual Justice League movie that has been green lighted after the success of Marvel's Avengers. It will not be confirmed until after the Superman reboot that's coming next year. So there was no time to introduce Robin as the Franchise had to go to make way for what they expect to be a bigger movie, believe it or not considering the success of Nolan's Batman franchise.

That being said, and after watching the ending of the TDKR... they're obviously toying with the idea of a Robin or Nightwing franchise in the Nolan "realistic" Universe because it is such a wildly popular adaptation.

I expect to see a spin-off Franchise dealing with how Robin becomes Nightwing in a few years. Otherwise what was the point of that ending?

Comment: Can you provide some evidence for your answer? There is a lot of very interesting information here but without a source to back it up I fear your answer may not receive the attention is deserves.

Comment: @RobinlScoming - I believe the ending was used solely to make you think. Anybody familiar with Nolan's films will agree that he often leave things for the viewers to decide for themselves. In this case, people discuss "Is Blake really Robin" etc, similar to the ending of Inception, where there were countless debated about whether or not the last scene is reailty. Nolan loves playing with the minds of his viewers, and often leaves things unsaid on purpose, allowing thr viewers to make up their own minds :)

Answer (score 6):

Nolan spoke to this in an [interview for Empire-Online](http://www.empireonline.com/interviews/interview.asp?IID=1609). In short, he simply found it difficult to imagine Robin fitting into the world he'd created:

> Q. **We have to ask about the Robin gag at the end. We’d always wondered how possible it would be to make that character work in this version
>   of the Batman universe, and this has to have been the only way.**
>
> Nolan: ***It is a little hard to imagine Robin working in that universe, so the idea had to be limited to that gag at the end.*** But Joe’s character is
>   very important to the story. In any movie you need a character looking
>   at proceedings the way you see them, and Joe’s character is that
>   character for this film. One of my favourite scenes is when John tells
>   Bruce how he knew he was Batman. It’s like that scene in The Prestige
>   where the little kid sees through Christian’s trick. Little kids, they
>   don’t have any illusions, they just see the truth of the situation. I
>   feel there’s a kind of spiritual connection between the two movies
>   there.